# Are rational surface singularities $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, algebraic-surfaces

I know that, in general, rational singularities are not necessarily $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein. So I ask:

> is there any positive result in this direction known for surfaces?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is *yes*. In fact, there is the following

> **Proposition 1.** Every $2$-dimensional rational singularity $(X, \, x)$ is analytically $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial, i.e. there exists an analytic neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that every Weil divisor on $V$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor.
>
> In particular, every $2$-dimensional rational singularity is $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein.

Concerning the particular case of  rational *Gorenstein* singularities, we have

> **Proposition 2.** For a $2$-dimensional normal singularity $(X, \, x)$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $(X, \, x)$ is a rational double point (i.e., a Du Val singularity);
> 2. $(X, \, x)$ is a rational hypersurface singularity;
> 3. $(X, \, x)$ is a rational Gorenstein singularity;
> 4. $(X, \, x)$ is a canonical singularity.

See S. Ishii, *[Introduction to Singularities](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9784431550808)*, Theorem 7.3.2 and Theorem 7.5.1.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm wondering also if there is a special case in which they are even Gorenstein?

Comment: Yes, they are classified. I have edited the answer.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the local divisor class group of a rational surface singularity is even a finite group, see for instance section 17 of  http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1969__36__195_0

Comment: The converse also holds (for singularities over algebraically closed fields too).  Finite divisor class group implies rational singularity for surfaces.